# loop device in a Linux container?

Tags: linux, containers, cgroup, loop-device

I'm attempting to use a loop device inside a container, to mount some image file:

```
> sudo losetup /dev/loop0 test.img
losetup: /dev/loop0: failed to set up loop device: No such file or directory
```

`/dev/loop0` indeed doesn't exist, and

```
> sudo mknod /dev/loop0 b 7 0
mknod: ‘/dev/loop0’: Operation not permitted
```

How can I make this work? Does the container need some cgroup permission that it might not have?

Answer (score 26):

If you're using systemd-nspawn, start up your container with the `--capability=CAP_MKNOD` command line switch. This will allow you to create device nodes inside your container. Then create a loop device like this:

```
# mknod /dev/loop0 b 7 0
```

Remember that this loop device is shared with the host and is called `/dev/loop0` there as well. And that it is now possible to access host devices if you know the major and minor numbers. There could also be other consequences that I haven't thought about. Be warned.

Comment: Can anybody confirm that `--capability=CAP_MKNOD` still works? For me it seems to have no effect, I get `Operation not permitted` even with it, and so do [this user](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199015) and [this user](http://armbian2.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=63042733&item=411).

Comment: I got it to work now, but in addition to giving `--capability=CAP_MKNOD` I had to set `DeviceAllow=block-loop rwm` in the systemd-nspawn unit  to make it work (got that idea from [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/3153ded003233b4431ee2fa4cea96cb987c08fd4/units/systemd-nspawn%40.service.in#L36-L40)).

Comment: I had to add `--device-cgroup-rule="b 7:* rmw"` to `docker run` to permit full access to loopback devices (but no others, since there's no `--privilege`). 

Found via https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/create/#dealing-with-dynamically-created-devices---device-cgroup-rule and tested on docker 18.06.1-ce (the document claims to only apply to Docker Edge)

Comment: This doesn't work if one is using user namespace.

Comment: I’m guessing this loop device doesn’t automatically get cleaned up when the container is destroyed? If so, that seems like a significant drawback.

Answer (score 19):

Loop devices are provided by a kernel module.  Therefore, you need special privileges to access them.  You also need them to be exposed into your container, or you need to manually create the device files.

**The quick answer**

```
docker run --privileged=true ...
```

**An alternative**

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 test.img
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
docker run -v /mnt:/mnt ...
```

**This almost works**

```
docker run --device=/dev/loop-control:/dev/loop-control --device=/dev/loop0:/dev/loop0 --cap-add SYS_ADMIN ...
```

However I get this error:

```
root@5c033d5f8625:/# sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
mount: block device /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount block device /dev/loop0 read-only
```

See this link for more [information](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/JmHko2nstWQ).

---

A note on systemd-nspawn man page:

> systemd-nspawn limits access to various kernel interfaces in the
>   container to read-only, such as /sys, /proc/sys or /sys/fs/selinux.
>   Network interfaces and the system clock may not be changed from within
>   the container. Device nodes may not be created. The host system cannot
>   be rebooted and kernel modules may not be loaded from within the
>   container.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that loopback devices are not cleaned up like mount points when the container exits.  This means the OS will not allow `test.img` to be fully deleted from the file system after the container exits, even if the file name is removed. The resources for that file will remain on disk or in-memory depending on where the file was created initially.